# How do I approach a linear mixed effects model with a 2-level group?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, mixed-model, group-differences, contrasts

My data looks something like this:

```
> head(my_data,n=8)

Subject Group     Value1     Value2   Outcome
1         A        12.404    5.00     1.33
2         A        14.898    4.34     6.77
3         A        13.870    2.53     5.01
4         A        14.313    9.33     6.82
5         B        13.407    4.99     8.42
6         B        13.480    2.59     9.11
7         B        13.761    1.42     8.21
8         B        12.607    0.55     8.32
...
...
```

I'm interested in performing a mixed linear effects model with a comparison between the Groups. I want to see the effect the group difference has on the different fixed variables (i.e. Value1 and Value2). I wasn't sure how to go about that.  Initially this is what I had:

```
lme(outcome*Group~ (Value1+Value2)*Group, random= ~ 1|Subject, data=my_data)
```

But once I read further, I thought it should look something like this:

```
lme(outocme~Value1+Value2+Group, random=1|Subject, data=my_data)
```

However, when I do that I get an output that only lists group A but not group B for some reason.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> I get an output that only lists group A but not group B for some reason.

Presumably, group B is the reference level, and since R uses contrast coding by default, B will be included in the intercept and the estimate for `Group` will be the estimated difference in the outcome variable between A and B

The difference between your two models is that the first one fits interactions between Group abd the other two variables, but the second one does not. It's a matter for your research question about which model to choose. Interactions occur when the "effect" of one variable differs at different levels of the other, so if yuo want the "effect" of those two variables to differ between group A and B, then fit the interactions, otherwise, don't.

Comment: @hsayya does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not then please let us know why